# List of strings between regex matches

Tags: python, regex

How do I find all the strings between a regex pattern?
For example,

```
>>> s="123 asd 12 456 sfd g 789"
>>> reg=re.compile("\d{3}")
>>> reg.findall(s)
['123', '456', '789']
```

I want to find:

```
[' asd 12 ', ' sfd g ']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`.split()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.split) instead of `.findall()`:

```
>>> reg.split(s)
['', ' asd 12 ', ' sfd g ', '']
```

It includes *all* results in between the matches, including the empty strings at the start and end. You can filter those out:

```
>>> filter(None, reg.split(s))
[' asd 12 ', ' sfd g ']
```

although on Python 3 you'd need to use `list(filter(None, reg.split(s)))`, or iterate over the result of `filter()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.split` instead of `re.findall`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
>>> reg = re.compile(r'(?:\d{3})?(.*?)\d{3}')
>>> reg.findall("123 asd 12 456 sfd g 789")
[' asd 12 ', ' sfd g ']
```

Since `.findall()` won't find overlapping matches, you need to specify the first group of numbers as being an optional match.  In the end, it might be better to take a different approach than regexes alone for a more robust solution.

Comment: Thanks! I think that's split() is more elegant and more explicit, thought.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = "123 asd 12 456 sfd g 789"
>>> filter(None, re.compile("\d{3}").split(s))
[' asd 12 ', ' sfd g ']
```